# Creating DNS A Record for 3 domain controllers

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

I have setup a new domain on our network consisting of 2 domain controllers, dc1, dc2.
I can see the A records for the 2 controllers. But I need to do load balancing so that I can refer to the 2 dcs in single entry.

I have created two A records  with same name for the different IPs, dc.domain.com. Is this the standards procedure?

Comment: **But I need to do load balancing so that I can refer to the 2 dcs in single entry** - Can  you tell us why you want/need to do "load balancing" and what you mean by that statement?

Comment: Thanks. I have an application with about 10,000 users which authenticates against the Active Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active directory *already has* a form of a DNS load balancing. You just look into wrong place.

`A` record just says which controller has which IP address. Where clients go for each domain service (LDAP, Kerberos, Global Catalog LDAP, et cetera) is configured with `SRV` records. And if you didn't do anything fancy, you will have `SRV` records in your domain already point to each domain controller for each service.

Here is the typical structure of the Active Directory domain DNS zone:

```
example.com.                               3600 IN SOA      dc1.example.com. admin.example.com 66593 900 600 86400 3600
example.com.                               3600 IN NS       dc1.example.com.
example.com.                               3600 IN NS       dc2.example.com.
example.com.                               600  IN A        192.168.3.1
example.com.                               600  IN A        192.168.4.1
_gc._tcp.example.com.                      600  IN SRV      0 100 3268 dc2.example.com.
_gc._tcp.example.com.                      600  IN SRV      0 100 3268 dc1.example.com.
_kerberos._tcp.example.com.                600  IN SRV      0 100 88 dc2.example.com.
_kerberos._tcp.example.com.                600  IN SRV      0 100 88 dc1.example.com.
_kpasswd._tcp.example.com.                 600  IN SRV      0 100 464 dc2.example.com.
_kpasswd._tcp.example.com.                 600  IN SRV      0 100 464 dc1.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.example.com.                    600  IN SRV      0 100 389 dc2.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.example.com.                    600  IN SRV      0 100 389 dc1.example.com.
_kerberos._udp.example.com.                600  IN SRV      0 100 88 dc2.example.com.
_kerberos._udp.example.com.                600  IN SRV      0 100 88 dc1.example.com.
_kpasswd._udp.example.com.                 600  IN SRV      0 100 464 dc2.example.com.
_kpasswd._udp.example.com.                 600  IN SRV      0 100 464 dc1.example.com.
DomainDnsZones.example.com.                600  IN A        192.168.3.1
DomainDnsZones.example.com.                600  IN A        192.168.4.1
_ldap._tcp.DomainDnsZones.example.com.     600  IN SRV      0 100 389 dc2.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.DomainDnsZones.example.com.     600  IN SRV      0 100 389 dc1.example.com.
ForestDnsZones.example.com.                600  IN A        192.168.3.1
ForestDnsZones.example.com.                600  IN A        192.168.4.1
_ldap._tcp.ForestDnsZones.example.com.     600  IN SRV      0 100 389 dc2.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.ForestDnsZones.example.com.     600  IN SRV      0 100 389 dc1.example.com.
dc1.example.com.                          3600  IN A        192.168.3.1
dc2.example.com.                          3600  IN A        192.168.4.1
_msdcs.example.com.                        3600 IN NS       dc1.example.com.
_gc._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 3268 dc1.example.com.
_kerberos._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 88 dc1.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 389 dc1.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.DomainDnsZones.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 389 dc1.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.ForestDnsZones.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 389 dc1.example.com.
_gc._tcp.alter-site._sites.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 3268 dc2.example.com.
_kerberos._tcp.alter-site._sites.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 88 dc2.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.alter-site._sites.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 389 dc2.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.alter-site._sites.DomainDnsZones.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 389 dc2.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.alter-site._sites.ForestDnsZones.example.com. 600 IN SRV 0 100 389 dc2.example.com.
```

If you create *sites*, you'll get additional records for them. That supposed to make some computer to preferably ask their local domain controller than the remote. Here `dc2` belongs to site `alter-site` and so any computer who is in that site will ask it first. If you leave everything default, both controllers will be in the default site `Default-First-Site-Name`.

You can alter the load distribution between controllers by altering those `SRV` records. See "100"'s? These are *weights*. If you set 67 for one DC and 33 for another, the first one will get 2/3 of requests and another will have 1/3. "0"'s in front of each `SRV` record are *priorities*; if you have larger priority servers accessible the lower priority will not be queiried at all. Please look for `SRV` record description for details; there are plenty explanations in the Internet, including this site.

There are few records which are "not symmetric". For example, `SOA` record has a particular DNS server name in it. But those are rarely used in this case and this doesn't constitute any bottlenecks.

Also important note about `SYSVOL`. When clients login, after checking passwords (which involves the *Kerberos* service), they ask the domain for group policies, and they do this using the *domain* name, not a particular DC name, like this: `\\example.com\SYSVOL` (and not, for example, `\\dc1.example.com\SYSVOL`). You can see a domain apex has several `A` records, one for each domain controller (4th and 5th lines of the example). The client will use randomly selected `A` record to connect, so each DC will have roughly the same share.

Answer (score 0):

You can do load balancing by simply using the domain name. There is usually an A record for each domain controller in the same as parent record.

Note: this is *not* high availability and should not be considered such.